# Simple JQuery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm trying to get a random generator of text and images which should be super simple but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's not working out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

HTML
    
    
    
        
        
        
        
        Scroll Demo #1

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p>Where would you live and what would you drive?</p>
        <p id="text"></p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#container {
width: 960px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: gray solid;
padding: auto;
background-image: url(../images/house.jpg) no-repeat;
}

#text {
font-size: 40px;
text-align: left;
}

p {
width: 100px;
color: black;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: left;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  var car = ["limo", "golf cart", "pig"];
  var images = ["house.jpg", "dumpster.jpg", "mansion.jpg"];

  var x = images[Math.Floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=car[x];
  $('html').css({'background-image':'url(images/' + images [x] + ')'});
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see any error in your console? What is the value of `x`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on script.js line 7 which is the var x=images[math.floor(math.random() *images.length)];

Comment: Did you try Blazemonger's suggestion?  you should have `var x = Math.Floor(Math.random() * images.length)`, not `x=images[math.floor(math.random() *images.length)];`

Comment: yes I responded to them below, it's still not working :(

Comment: Please try to use `console.log(x)` and tell me the result.

Comment: I added that under the `var x=` statement, I'm not exactly sure what it's supposed to do but nothing changed. Obviously I'm new at this haha.

Comment: Okay figured out that I had to put it into the console. Banik below figured it out for me. `Math.Floor` was capitalized.

Comment: Yes, I got it, the correct way is `Math.floor` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to expect `x` to be a number, not an image:

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length); // not Floor
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I did change and it's still not behaving accurately. :(

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. I can't believe that was the problem. You're the best!!